# Counting occurrences of words in PokemonGO subreddit using Python

Tags: python, reddit

I have to count the occurrence of Charizard, Valor, Mystic, Instinct, Pokemon, pokémon (uppercase and lowercase) in the top 500 all time post titles on the pokemonGO subreddit (r/pokemonGO/)

I got the answers for Charizard, Valor, Mystic and Instinct correct. However my value of Pokemon (Pokemon+pokémon) is 122. The correct value is 129. My code is below; what have I missed out?

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request
import json
import praw
import requests 
from pprint import pprint 
import string

Charizard = 0
Pokemon = 0
Valor = 0
Instinct = 0
Mystic = 0
numtitle = 0
url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/top.json?sort=top&t=all&limit=100"
i = 0
for j in range(5):
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': "orew"})
    data = r.json()
    for i in range((len(data["data"]["children"]))):
        title = (data['data']['children'][i]["data"]  ['title']).lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        if "charizard" in title.split():
            Charizard += 1
        if "pokemon" in title.split():
            Pokemon += 1
        if "pokémon"in title.split():
            Pokemon += 1
        if "valor" in title.split():
            Valor += 1
        if "mystic" in title.split():
            Mystic += 1
        if "instinct" in title.split():
            Instinct += 1
        numtitle += 1
    url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/top.json? sort=top&t=all&limit=100&after=" + data["data"]["after"]
    print(url)
print("The number of occurrences for Charizard is:",(Charizard))
print("The number of occurrences for Pokemon is:", (Pokemon))
print("The number of occurrences for Valor is:",(Valor))
print("The number of occurrences for Mystic is:",(Mystic))
print("The number of occurrences for Instinct is:",(Instinct))
print(numtitle)
```

Comment: Where do you get the 'correct' figures from? Also, some words may be present in the title more than once.

Comment: This was a homework task so I referred to the answers. Also, @ForceBru can you tell me how to count in the repetitions

Comment: I used title.split() but that doesn't seem to be enough

Comment: `title` is a string, and you wanna count the number of occurrences of some substring in it. There is a built-in function to do just that. Please consult the Python docs for type `string`.